# How do you identify references when there aren't any to give?

Tags: references

So, I am just curious - not currently on the market - about references.

I have worked a few jobs in the US in the time I have been here and should, in theory, have a lot of references. However, of the jobs I have worked a lot have been contract positions and those companies have previously stated that they don't do references for contractors and of my non-contract positions all of my references have died since I took this last position.

So, what should I do for references should I want to move to another company?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I was writing the question as I was talking to somebody else and didn't see the spelling issues.

Comment: By, "move to another company", you theoretically would intend that in a non-contractor way right?

Comment: Also, by "all of my references have died", what do you mean?... :0 do you mean that the person that hired you (your previous boss/manager) is no longer there or... well... is no longer able to serve as a reference for you?

Comment: @DarkCygnus even for contract jobs I need references, but this would be preferably not a contract job, as for what I mean by all my previous references have died is that the people are no longer living for one reason or another.

Comment: References don't need to be from "official" company representatives. Do you not have any colleagues, ex-colleagues, coworkers, or ex-coworkers that that can provide a reference for you?

Comment: The statements "all of my references have died" and "are no longer living for one reason or another" sound extremely sinister. The general content doesn't imply anything sinister here, and I am not saying there is, just that you might want to adjust your wording (e.g. not use "all" when there might have been a streak of people dying, but hardly "all" of them, or did they?).

Comment: @imsodin I have 3 non-contract references from the last 10 years. One had a heart attack this year, one committed suicide last year, and the third just got taken by the virus two weeks ago. I'm accepting the given answer because I thought references had to be management

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, what should I do for references should I want to move to another company?

You state that all of your non-contractor references are no longer able to give you one. However, there must be *at least someone* from that previous job you had that could help you as a reference.

Perhaps your previous bosses or managers passed away, or are no longer in that position, but I am sure that **you should have at least one coworker or acquaintance from that job that could be willing to be your reference**.

Yes, it's ideal to list your former managers as references, but if you are unable to do so, including past coworkers is also a valid option.

In any case, when you think of a past coworker/acquaintance that you could list, remember to contact them *first* to get their permission to list them as references, so they are aware in advance that they may expect a call.

Comment: Not necessarily about the coworkers.  I work primarily as an adjunct teaching for online schools.  Literally the only people I interact with are managers/department chairs.  I may see other adjuncts' name on a list during online staff meetings but I never really interact with them - certainly not to the point where they could provide a reference.  I suspect that contractors in the OP's industry may be similarly siloed.

Comment: @G.Allen how about students or a TA?

Answer (score 1):

If you found the contracts through an agency, they will be able to confirm your employment history.

It's nice to think that a reference will tell a recruiter that you're wonderful but many big companies have HR policies to do no more than confirm your employment dates and job title - all the recruiter needs is to check that you're not lying about your history.